# Alterar dimensão para ativar nav-toggle antes

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Estou fazendo um site e estou usando `bootstrap` nele. Testei no celular e quando mostra o menu, o menu ainda está da mesma forma que no PC só com a fonte menor. Queria mostrar aquele botão de abrir o menu no celular, creio que tenho que diminuir a resolução para ele ativar. Aonde eu faço isso no `bootstrap` ?

**HTML**

```
<div id="custom-bootstrap-menu" class="navbar navbar-default " role="navigation">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-menubuilder"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-menubuilder">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                        <li><a href="<?php echo site_url();?>">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('construtora');?>">A Construtora</a></li>
                        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('area');?>">Áreas de Atuação</a></li>
                        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('clientes');?>">Clientes</a></li>
                        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('contato');?>">Contato</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.navbar-nav{
    border-top:1px solid #1C6597;
    border-bottom:1px solid #1C6597;
}

#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default {
    font-size: 20px;
    border-width: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    font-family: 'Dosis';
}
.navbar-default{
    background: none !important;
    border:0px !important;
    margin-top:30px;
}


.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li{
    margin-left:40px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover{
    color: rgba(28, 101, 151, 1);
}

#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
    color: rgba(28, 101, 151, 1);
    background-color: rgba(56, 56, 181, 1);
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
    border-color: #3838b5;
}

#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background-color: #3838b5;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover .icon-bar,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus .icon-bar {
    background-color: #3838b5;
}
```

Comment: Poste o código  que voce fez para que possamos analisar, por default o navbar realiza isto http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar apos o comentário   `<!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display --!>`

Comment: @Highlander Código adicionado

Comment: No meu navegador esta normal : https://jsfiddle.net/708qb1qL/2/

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que seja necessário referenciar no seu css, tente colocar:

```
.navbar-toggle {
    padding: 4px 6px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #;
}
.navbar-toggle:focus,
.navbar-toggle:active {
    outline: 0;
}
```